# Cant match "Int -> Bool" with actual type "(Int,Bool)"

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a simple code to add numbers in the list with the correct conditions into a new list. But I'm getting an error that one of the input is (Int, Bool) instead of Int, how did this happen? Here's the code I'm writing

```
module FilterList where

-- Definisi dan Spesifikasi
countIf :: [Int] -> (Int,Bool) -> [Int]
{-Mencari elemen yang memenuhi kriteria tertentu-}
isPos :: Int -> Bool
{-True jika positif-}
isNeg :: Int -> Bool
{-True jika negatif-}
isKabisat :: Int -> Bool
{-True jika berada pada tahun kabisat (dapat dibagi 4 atau 400 tetapi tidak bisa dibagi 100)-}
isEmpty :: [Int] -> Bool
{-True jika list kosong-}

-- Realisasi
isEmpty li = (length li) == 0
isPos a = a >= 0
isNeg a = a < 0
isKabisat a = (mod a 4) == 0 && ((mod a 100) /= 0 || (mod a 400) == 0) 
countIf li func
    | isEmpty li = []
    | func (head li) = [] ++ [head li] ++ countIf (tail li) func
    | otherwise = [] ++ countIf (tail li) func
```

Some stuff are in Indonesian but only in the comments so the general idea is still there.

Comment: You have defined that countIf should take `[Int]` (a list of integers) and `(Int, Bool)` (a tuple of an integer and a boolean), but your implementation suggests that you want the second argument to be a function. A tuple isn't the same as a function, so the error tells you that the type should be a function type (`int -> Bool`)

Answer (score 6):

The signature is wrong: the `func` is a predicate, so:

```
countIf :: [Int] -> (Int -> Bool) -> [Int]
```

Your `isEmpty` function is however equivalent to [**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) (which is more efficient), and `countIf` is a special version of a "flipped" version of [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter). The name `countIf` also suggests that you are *counting* the number of matched elements, not a list of items that match the predicate.

Using `[] ++ xs` makes not much sense: this will simply return the `xs`, and `[x] ++ ys` is equivalent to `x : ys`. You use pattern matching to avoid using `head` and `tail`, so:

```
countIf :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
countIf [] func = []
countIf (h:t) func
    | func h = h : countIf t func
    | otherwise = countIf t func
```

but `countIf` can thus be implemented as:

```
countIf :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
countIf = flip filter
```

Comment: I'm writing countIf as a function to produce the output as a list for numbers which fit the criteria of the function. If [] ++ [head li] does not return a list, can I have the format for returning a list?

Comment: I'm not really following what the problem is. Exactly what do you try to do and what is not working.

Comment: @Nicholas438 `[] ++ [head li]` does return a list. But `[head li]` *also* returns a list, and it returns the same list, and it is simpler.